# How to delete a line containing pattern which is first found after a specific pattern

Tags: shell, unix

I am writting a shell script to delete an entry from a specific group. eg: file name is dest.xml

```
<domain id="1" group_name="group1">
    <node id="ABC">
    <node id="PQR">
    <node id="XYZ">
</domain>
<domain id="2" group_name="group2">
    <node id="PQR">
    <node id="XYZ">
</domain>
<domain id="3" group_name="group3">
    <node id="ABC">
    <node id="PQR">
 </domain>
```

I want to delete an entry from above file (filename is dest.xml) with node id="PQR" from group_name="group1" (it should not get deleted from group2 and group3). I can do it by reading a file sequentially n then delete it from a specific group. But if the file is to large (>10k lines) then it takes time.

Is there any simple way to this this?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
echo '<domain id="1" group_name="group1">
    <node id="ABC">
    <node id="PQR">
    <node id="XYZ">
</domain>
<domain id="2" group_name="group2">
    <node id="PQR">
    <node id="XYZ">
</domain>
<domain id="3" group_name="group3">
    <node id="ABC">
    <node id="PQR">
 </domain>' | sed -e '/group_name="group1"/,/<\/domain>/ { /node id="PQR"/d; }'
<domain id="1" group_name="group1">
    <node id="ABC">
    <node id="XYZ">
</domain>
<domain id="2" group_name="group2">
    <node id="PQR">
    <node id="XYZ">
</domain>
<domain id="3" group_name="group3">
    <node id="ABC">
    <node id="PQR">
 </domain>
```

#### Suggested usage:

```
mv dest.xml dest.bak && sed -e '/group_name="group1"/,/<\/domain>/ { 
        /node id="PQR"/d; 
    }' dest.bak > dest.xml
```

#### Korn Shell:

Note that environment variables are not expanded within single-quotes. If you wish to embed this command in a script, you'll need to use double quotes for the [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) command and then escape the double quotes within the program:

```
#!/bin/ksh
gp_name=group1
entry=PQR
mv dest.xml dest.bak && sed -e "/group_name=\"${gp_name}\"/,/<\/domain>/ {
    /node id=\"${entry}\"/d;
}" dest.bak > dest.xml
```

Comment: Hi john, Thanks for your help. Its working butwhen I use variables instead of directly giving value then its not working. I wrote script #!/bin/ksh

gp_name=group1
entry=PQR

mv dest.xml dest.bak && sed -e '/group_name="$gp_name"/,/<\/domain>/ {
        /node id="$entry"/d;
}' dest.bak > dest.xml
where I am going wrong?